# How do i create aws config and credential in windows system.?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have accidentally deleted aws credential and config file from  the location *c:\user\admin.aws.*
 
 
 Now when i use the **aws** **cli** through **powershell** its throwing an error saying profile not found ,i am unable to create or get those two files. How do i do it?

I tried creating these files using notepad which did not work for me.

Comment: `aws configure`

Comment: when i run this command i get the following error. ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name). It is not asking me for they key_id,and secret key

Comment: make it again by yourself. See [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html)

Comment: I tried that too. But its still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the path for the files would be "c:\users\admin\.aws\", right?

Once the files are added there, with the right settings, just try

> `aws sts get-caller-identity`

to check if the profile's configuration files are accessible by the command line.